# Form Validation magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I create form on success page with id varification-sms-code and add class input-text required-entry validate-email but not working

```
var validator = new Validation('varification-sms-code', {immediate : true});
validator.validate();
```

Comment: what logic for this validation class

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var validatoryourForm = new VarienForm('your-form-Id', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: i have done but nothing happen

Comment: <div class="verification_form" style="display:none">
    <form id="varification-sms-code">
 
 <input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_varification_number" type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" >
 
 <input type="button" class="button" onclick="return mobileConfirmation();" value="Send">
 </form>
 
</div>

Comment: this is my form code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
 var validatoryourForm = new VarienForm('varification-sms-code', true); 
     
    //]]>
</script>

Comment: and this is script

Comment: all is happen on succes page

Comment: please do change <button type="submit"

Comment: for testing remove onclick="return mobileConfirmation();"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
     var validator = new VarienForm('varification-sms-code', true);
   //]]>
 </script>
```